# How to host multiple reactJs web app under one domain in amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url-rewriting, aws-amplify

I've 2 different reactJs applications which can be deployed independently to aws-amplify. Is there a way I can configure them to the different context paths of the same domain?

```
www.mydomain.com/app1
www.mydomain.com/app2
```

Is it possible using amplify?

Comment: I have same requirement.
But, My projects are hosted on two EC2 instances.
Instance1 for proj1
instance2 for proj2

I want to load both projects as below: 

www.mydomain.com/app1
www.mydomain.com/app2

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Amplify documentation says you can use "200 redirects" (or "Reverse proxy rewrite") to deal with this issue.
cf. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html

I quote :

> Rewrite (200)
>
> 200 redirects (rewrites) are intended to show content from the
> destination address as if it were served from the original address.
> Search engine ranking history continues to apply to the original
> address. Redirection occurs on the server-side, so a browser
> navigation bar shows the original address after redirection.

So you can create 3 amplify projects.

- a "router" project
- app1 project
- app2 project

### Domain configuration

The router project is set with your domain [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com).

app1 and app2 projects doesn't need to have specific domain, let's keep their default domain : branch.PROJECT_ID.amplifyapp.com.

example :
master.xxxx1.amplifyapp.com
master.xxxx2.amplifyapp.com

### Redirect rules configuration

nothing in this project except 2 redirect rules :

```
/app1/<*>   https://master.xxxx1.amplifyapp.com/<*>    200
/app2/<*>   https://master.xxxx2.amplifyapp.com/<*>    200
```

et voilà ! ;)

But I think Nikhil Chauhan's monorepo solution is the best. I didn't know about it. ^^

Comment: How do search engines handle this? Do they still consider _example.com/app1_ as a new page of _example.com_? And what about _app1.mydomain.com/_, does it get the same ranking as _example.com/app1_?

Comment: @DavidAlberici 
it is transparent for SEO. 
"200 redirect" allows the url not to change, unlike 301 or 302 redirect.
so robots don't see the difference between www.domain.com/app1 and app1.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've figured out is adding subdomains before

Let me know if you figure this out because I'm trying to do the same thing

I'll keep you posted as well

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no way to deploy multiple projects with different subdirectories on the same domain using different amplify projects.

But there is a way to deploy multiple projects under the same domain name in a single amplify project instance. If your project is using a monorepo style of structuring the projects. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/monorepo-configuration.html) .

Comment: Hey @Nikhil Chauhan, were you able to figure out how to deploy multiple projects under the same domain having different subdirectories? If so, could you share some more details on how to set that up?